# Неправильно обрабатывается запрос mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать запрос в БД на php, но опыт в языке стремится к нулю. Запрос не выполняется верно, хотя callback пишет, что все ок. В чем проблема?

```
function donateForAccount($account, $count)
{
    $account = (string)$account;
    $count = (float)$count;

    $query = 
        "INSERT INTO 
            mtaAccess (serial, donat)
        VALUES 
            (".$account.", ".$count.")";

    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Comment: ааа, для чего values между точками ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский передача значений в таблицу мускула

Comment: я не уверен но вроде бы без точек надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот запрос:

```
$query = 
    "INSERT INTO 
        mtaAccess (serial, donat)
    VALUES 
        ('{$account}', '{$count}')";
```

И ещё. Зачем вы сделали явно выраженный тип переменных? PHP сам умеет преобразовывать тип переменной по необходимости. За исключением случаев сравнения, когда необходимо указать точный тип, чтобы получить правильное сравнение.

Comment: Благодарю:)
Говорю же в php опыта нет, пишу на другом языке. 
Интегрирую игру с сайтом через мускул.

Comment: PHP самый демократичный язык. Поэтому в нём можно позволять себе многие вольности, такие как неявный тип переменной.